# Count associations from a where clause active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a list of Parents who have many Children and each Child has one and only one skill. The parents have a many-to-many relationship to children and Children can have the same skill.

I am trying to get a list of all parents and add a count field of how many children they have with a particular skill. Is this possible with active record?

My current solution uses this `Parent.joins(:children).select('parents.*, COUNT(*) AS child_count').group('parents.id').where(children: {skill_name: skill})`

This however doesn't return Parents with a count of 0 for child_count. Is there any way to accomplish this with Active Record? I want to return JSON for every parent with a count of how many of their children have a specific skill.

Answer (score 0):

`.joins(:children)` generates an INNER JOIN which will exclude parents with 0 children. You should change it to an OUTER JOIN. For the most part you cannot do this with ActiveRecord (unless you want to perform eager loading, too). Assuming that your join table is named `parents_children`, then you can build the join yourself:

```
.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN parents_children ON parents_children.parent_id = parents.id INNER JOIN children ON parents_children.child_id = children.id")
```